# Creating a large number of identical sprites that can play animations independantly

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser as my game engine. I have a group of around 2400 sprites that all have the same texture. The call

```
group.callAll('animations.add', 'animations', tileName, [1], 1);
```

takes around 5 seconds and I need to make a few of these calls. This makes my game load for around 30 seconds and it will increase drastically when I add more content.
Is there a faster way to make a lot of basically identical sprites, but still be able to play animations on them separately?

I asked the same question in a Github issue but I figured someone other than the developers might know the answer.

Comment: Could you please link that github issue?

Comment: Well, sure, but it's the identical question as I've written it here. https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/823